# Will trenbolone acetate in the presence of methanol yield trenbolone acetate if distilled water is subsequently added thereafter?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, precipitation

I have 2 grams of trenbolone acetate. I was told to add it to 20 ml of methanol. Then wait until it is fully dissolved. Then distilled water is to be added yeilding a precipitate that is supposed to still be trenbolone. Can anyone shed light on this? 
Here is [the link](http://www.basskilleronline.com/crystal-tren.shtml).

Answer (score 1):

The method will not convert trenbolone acetate to trenbolone, the ester is not cleaved under these conditions.

[image]

It is however possible to separate the **steroid** from a mixture with other, water-soluble compounds this way.

Unless you are a veterinarian and use trenbolone or its acetate as a **growth promoter** for cattle, you might want to consider the legal situation in your country. As far as Germany is concerned, the possession of as much as 2 g might lead to real trouble. Here, the non-punishable, non-significant amount is in the 150 mg range (for its use in sports).